# Trying to set java compiler to compliance level to 5.0

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to compile some facebook sample code in eclipse and it says I need compliance level 5.0 or 6.0.
I tried to set the compliance level by:

1. right clicking on project name
   b. clicked on properties -> java compiler

on the drop down for compliance level, it had
   1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6 and 1.7 but did not have 5.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java versioning is somewhat odd and annoying. `1.6` and `1.7` are well-known examples but generally you can get away with using `1.X` for `X`. Here you'd use `1.5`.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to asnwer my quastion, so simple just did not think of that.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is that 5.0 is the same as 1.5.
Since java 1.5, the names are denoted without a leading `1.`
[source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#J2SE_5.0_.28September_30.2C_2004.29)

Answer (score 1):

Java 1.5 *is* 5.0. You can read about this [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#J2SE_5.0_.28September_30.2C_2004.29):

> #### J2SE 5.0 (September 30, 2004)
>
> Codename **Tiger**. Originally numbered 1.5, which is still used as the internal version number. This version was developed under JSR 176.